# EF Code First Migration + Multiple DbContext + Foreign Key

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm building an Asp.Net application with EF6 Code First. I have created two projects. (One main project and a class library project). Both projects have Model classes and their own DbContext class, however both projects shares same connection string and a database.

```
//Model from Project A
public class Product
{
   public int ProductId{get;set;}
}


//Model from Project B
public class Invoice
{
   public int InvoiceId{get;set;}

   [ForeignKey("Product")]
   public int ProductId{get;set;}

   public virtual Product Product
}
```

Here I'm referencing `ProjectA.Product.ProductId` inside  ProjectB as `ProjectB.Invoice.ProductId` (Foreign key constraint)

**Problem**

- Executed the code first migration in Project A: Migration executed without an issue.
- Executed the code first migration in Project B: Error

> There is already an object named 'Product' in the database.

Seems when executing migration for Project A which creates the table Product in Database and later on, When executing migration for Project B, seems EF tries to create the table Product again.

I have read many articles in, but not found any solution yet.
How can I Solve this issue? Can anyone help me by providing a solution?

P.S: I'm inheriting project context class from BaseContext class, which inherits from DbContext class.

I have enabled automatic migrations in each projects.

Comment: Perhaps move your EF code to a third project. The migrations would occur in that project. Then Project A and Project B get a reference to Project Data. No double migration.

Comment: @Jasen I don't want to do that, coz I have to maintain some standards. In future, I will add more sub projects.

Comment: See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx). Go down to the part where she mentions an 'uber-model' that encompasses everything.

Comment: @SteveGreene my contextClasses are inherits from a base class. Will that work for me?Could you please provide an example?